# Clone github enterprise private repo in CodeBuild

Tags: github, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm setting up a CICD pipeline using AWS CodePipeline and CodeBuild which gets triggered from a private Github Enterprise repo.

I need access to this repo in the build step of my pipeline, so I'm cloning it using a command like this in my buildspec.yml file:

```
git clone https://<user>:<token>@github.ent.companydomain.com/xxx/xxx.git
```

This is giving me a `403 Forbidden` error even though the repo exists and the URL is correct. How do I clone my repo in build step?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `git-credential-helper: yes` inside env of your buildspec.yml file.

Also check whether you have provided proper access token if you are using github as source provider and authorised it via AWS console